# Add with statement in non verbose mode in fabric (Python)

Tags: python, fabric

I have the following code now

```
if (verbose):

   with hide('running', 'stdout', 'stderr'):
       line 1
       line 2
else:
    line 1
    line 2
```

Is there any way to avoid the repetition of line1 and line 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def dothisstuff():
   line 1
   line 2

if (verbose):
   with hide('running', 'stdout', 'stderr'):
       dothisstuff()
else:
    dothisstuff()
```

Though this might be overkill for only 2 repetitions of 2 lines. But I assume it are more then 2 lines :)

Comment: Thanks. Sometimes I miss the obvious things while looking for complicated solutions :).